# Push notification to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Since manifest version 3, background scripts (now known as service workers) aren’t persistent, so I can’t think of a way to register a listener (e.g. web socket) that will receive notifications from my server.

I read about the `chrome.gcm` API, but I understand GCM is deprecated (and unusable) in favor of FCM.

Is it possible in any way to send messages from my server to my Chrome extension?

Comment: No, MV3 has broken all such extensions and no one knows if a fix will be available before MV2 dies. Meanwhile the only workaround is to force the worker to be alive, [more info](/q/66618136/).

Comment: @wOxxOm that’s terrible.. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.gcm` API is in fact using firebase under the hood, there's a bug report in chromium to address the documentation issues and add self-explaining alias to the API methods - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1337382